# ¿Cómo buscar si una palabra está contenida dentro de un texto?

Tags: javascript, datatables

estoy configurando en un datatable que cambie de color la fila según el valor la primera columna, pero no siempre el valor es igual, dependiendo de la hora hay diferentes, aquí os dejo el ejemplo:

```
if (data[0] == "MATEMATICAS 20:30")
    {
        $(row).addClass('td:eq(0)').css("background-color", "#e1f0d9").css("color", "#477540").css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
```

Quiero que todas las que aparezca la palabra **MATEMATICAS** las incluya, **independientemente de si tiene texto delante o detrás**, he probado  cambiando los `==` por los demás operadores lógicos y hasta probando como en excel **`"*MATEMATICAS*"`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)**. De esta manera, si contuviera la palabra MATEMATICAS, cambiaría tu CSS.

La función `indexOf` devuelve el índice de la primera ocurrencia de la palabra. En caso de que no encontrara la palabra, devolvería -1.

```
if (data[0].indexOf("MATEMATICAS") >= 0)
{
    $(row).addClass('td:eq(0)').css("background-color", "#e1f0d9").css("color", "#477540").css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

**NOTA:** La función `indexOf` es case sensitive, es decir, tiene en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas. En caso de que no quisieras tener en cuenta las mayúsculas y las minúsculas podrías utilizar las funciones **[`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase)** o **[`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toLowerCase)**, que convierten todo el texto a mayúsculas o minúsculas respectivamente.

```
if (data[0].toUpperCase().indexOf("MATEMATICAS") >= 0){
   //Tu código aquí
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YO cambiaria tu idea inicial y plantearia añadir en cada identificador fila **tr** una clase de asignatura: tipo :

```
<tr class="matematicas"> o <tr class="fisica">
```

luego, tu css tendria que declarar esas clases:

```
<style>
.matematicas {
   background-color: red;
}

.fisica {
   background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

con eso directamente no necesitarias utilizar js.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

1.- `indexOf()`

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
>
> **Note**: **The indexOf() method is case sensitive**.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp

```js
var str = "MATEMATICAS 20:30";
if(str.indexOf("MATEMATICAS")>-1)
{
  console.log("Contiene MATEMATICAS");
}
```

2.- `match()`

> The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular
>   expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

```js
var str = "MATEMATICAS 20:30"; 
var res = str.match(/MATEMATICAS/g);
if(res.length>0)
{
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.length);
}
```

Tendrás que tener en cuenta mayúsculas, acentos, etc.